# Typescript - Cast string to custom complex object

Tags: typescript, casting

I have this **string** returned by an automated system.

```
"[
      {
        key: "FACTORY",
        prefix: () => h(NButton, { text: true, type: "primary" }, { default: () => "FACTORY" }),
        children: [
            {
              label: "id", key: "id",
              suffix: () => h(NButton, { text: true, type: "primary" }, { default: () => "marco" }),
            },
              {
                label: "groove", key: "groove",
                children: [
                    {
                      label: "shape", key: "shape",
                      suffix: () => h( NButton, { text: true, type: "primary" }, { default: () => "box" } ),
                    },
                ],
              }
        ],
      },
    ]"
```

It is a javascript object good to populate the [Naive-UI NTree](https://www.naiveui.com/en-US/os-theme/components/tree#filter.vue) component.
The Naive-UI component require a **TreeOption[]** type to run fine.

```
export interface TreeOptionBase {
    key?: Key;
    label?: string;
    checkboxDisabled?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    isLeaf?: boolean;
    children?: TreeOption[];
    prefix?: () => VNodeChild;
    suffix?: () => VNodeChild;
}
export declare type TreeOption = TreeOptionBase & {
    [k: string]: unknown;
};
```

How to convert my generated string to  **TreeOption[]** type ?

Thank's in advance

Comment: What is `h()`?  If it depends on some external library you should tag the question as depending on it.  Otherwise you should either define `h()` in your question or remove it from the example code.  Please note that your string is invalid; inline line breaks cannot appear like that.   Maybe you want to use a template literal string instead?

Comment: @jcalz To clarification, I addes a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naive-ui-ntree-dynamic-ditx82?file=/src/Demo.vue) as demo. 
Using `data_ok` it run fine, but the output of the automated system is  a string.
The challenge is use `data_as_string` as source of "data" property.

Comment: Please include all code necessary for a [mre] directly in the question as plain text; a link to an external IDE project is a good supplement but not a replacement for having a self-contained example on Stack Overflow itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `JSON.parse` change `String` to `Array`.